# Maximum Hight of a panel in Split Container

Tags: c#, winforms, split, resize, max

How can I set the minimum & maximum height of a panel in a horizontal split container in my C# form?

Comment: Yes. this is winform.

Comment: Have you found the SplitContainer.Panel1MinSize and Panel2MinSize properties back yet?  They restrict the movement of the splitter.  The maximum size for a panel is implicit from the container's size minus the other panel's minimum size, there is no scenario where you leave a gap between the panels.

Comment: @HansPassant There's the scenario where your split container hasn't a defined size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SplitContainer has 2 fields: Panel1MinSize and Panel2MinSize. To set the maximum size for panel1 just set the appropriate  min size for panel2.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is old, but I couldn't find a suitable answer anywhere I looked.  Some people suggested setting Panel1 as a fixed panel, which was not what I wanted.  I solved this issue by using by using the splitcontainers sizeChanged and SplitterMoved events:

```
    private const int Panel1MaxWidth = 1075;
    private void splitContainer1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(splitContainer1.Panel1.Width > Panel1MaxWidth)
        {
            splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = Panel1MaxWidth;
        }
    }

    private void splitContainer1_SplitterMoved(object sender, SplitterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (splitContainer1.Panel1.Width > Panel1MaxWidth)
        {
            splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = Panel1MaxWidth;
        }
    }
```

Just set the Pane1MaxWidth constant to whatever you want your maximum size of Panel1 to expand out to.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of where the `Panel` is, you could normally specify the maximum height and width by doing:

```
panel1.MaximumSize = new Size(300, 300); //max 300 x 300
```

If you use `SplitContainer` and your `Panel` is inside the `SplitContainer`, and you want to change it while it is in the `SplitContainer`, however, you might need to identify if the `Panel` is in the `Panel1` or `Panel2` of the `SplitContainer` before you specify the max height and width as above. Something like this:

```
//assuming the name "panel1" in the Panel1 of the SplitContainer
Panel panel = splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls["panel1"];
panel.MaximumSize = new Size(300, 300); //max 300 x 300
```

However, if what you want is to change the `splitContainer` size itself, you could apply the `MaximumSize` for the `splitContainer` as well:

```
splitContainer1.MaximumSize = new Size(300, 300);
```

Or, if you want to change the `splitContainer.Panel1` or `splitContainer.Panel2`, you could also try to play with `SplitContainer.SplitterDistance` property.

Comment: That does not prevent the Splitter from being dragged.